# AVD running in eclipse barely ever runs app

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error, android-virtual-device

I'm new to android development and don't currently own an android device so I'm relying on the avd to run my app but it is being highly unpredictable.

I'm currently at the stage that I have the menu screen of my app set up and have been testing it in a step by step fashion as follows:

- I placed all of the graphics on the screen and the app ran just fine.
- I added a function to press the sound button to disable sounds and change the "sound active" button to a "sound deactive" button.
- When I tried running the app in the avd it opened and displayed the title bar and the top bar. Normally it opens like this but after a brief pause the bars would be hidden and the app would run. But this time it just displayed the title bar and didn't go any further.
- After restarting eclipse the app ran just fine and my changes worked.
- I added 2 lines of code (an if statement and a play sound statement) to make the button play a sound when sound is activated.
- Now the app will only display the title and will not advance any further. I have restarted eclipse and my compter several times and the problem persists. I have not modified any of the files other than the menu file since the last time it ran perfectly and logCat displays no errors except for an activity idle timeout after a few minutes.

Looking online for the problem only leads me to questions regarding apps not starting at all. I have tried the solutions for those problems even though they aren't the same as my problem.

EDIT:

It now works without me changing any code. After my computer had been off overnight it runs just fine. Although any answer that I can get to the problem would help if anything happens again.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for your onClick method?  Likely you are trying to do something on the UI thread that is taking a long time to run.

Comment: It doesn't even run far enough for me to click so I think it's something to do with the main activity although I haven't modified that or the manifest file since it last worked but here's basically what happens on click: 
    `settings.soundEnabled = !settings.soundEnabled;  
    if (soundEnabled)  
    assets.click.play();`   Not really enough code to take a long time to run.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any errors in your logCat output?

I had a similar problem with MapView - I solved it to set GooleAPI as target not Android.

Comment: No errors just a timeout warning. I've left it running for the past hour to see if anything else happens. I'll try using googleAPI

Answer (score 0):

It think it would be best to look at the LogCat results first. If there is a reason why the app doesn't want to load it will probably be in there.
To open the LogCat results in Eclipse: Window > Show View > LogCat

Another thing you could try, which will sometimes solve the problem, is to clean your project. Especially after some developing/testing time this is a good idea.
In Eclipse: Project > Clean..